# Updating a key in a OData services

Tags: database, service, sql-update, odata, primary-key

I wrote the following statement to update a entry in my OData service:

```
PUT /HOData/library.xsodata/books('HAPI%20Hana%20Integration%20Test%20Volume%201') HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
accept: application/atom+xml
Content-Type: application/atom+xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:g="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <id>http://odata.host/unknown:</id>
    <title/>
    <updated>2014-07-17T08:26:23.939Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="HOData.library.booksType"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:title>HAPI Hana Integration Test Volume 1</d:title>
            <d:ISBN>ISBN-13: 978-0-321-71838-9</d:ISBN>
            <d:editions m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:editions>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

it works fine when I try update a property that is not a key of the entity. For this case the key of the entity is **title**. So, anybody knows if for update a key in an OData service should I do something different or this is a problem with OData V2 or still this is a problem with my service?

Thank you
Pablo

Comment: What is the response or error message if 'title' in the request payload is not the same as the original one? error returned or just keep no changed?

Comment: As title is a key of the schema, if the title were different from one that exists on the database the response will be an error of not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OData spec, keys are non-updatable properties. In order to work this scenario around, you can delete the entity whose key you want to update and post a new entity with the key you wanted and other properties being identical to the other properties of the deleted entity.